# Is it possible to perform statistical analysis comparing a percentage from 1 group to a reference group?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, epidemiology

I am comparing dog breeds with a specific disease in my study to a population of registered dogs (no disease information known). The population of registered dogs is not a true reference population, so I can't perform Chi square analysis or anything to look at breed predispositions, but I was wondering if I could still use the data to look at potential overrepresentations?

At the moment, I'm comparing proportions of breeds in the study with the proportion that are registered.

Example: 
Staffordshire Bull Terriers in study = 14/117 (12%)
Staffordshire Bull Terriers in registered population = 6698/100674 (6.7%)

Is it possible to compare them, and see if the proportion of Staffies in my study is significantly different to the 6.7% in the registered population?

Comment: Check http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78474/correct-test-for-proportions or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32546/two-sample-test-of-proportions But I'm wondering what is aim of your study? Why do you want to compare dogs breed by breed between the two populations? Do you (or why not) compare the overall prevalence of disease between the two populations? There may be hierarchical structure of your data: overall effect of population and breed-specific effects that may need accounting for. How were dogs from your study matched to the reference group (or why not)?

Comment: My aim is to evaluate whether there are breeds predisposed to developing this particular disease (intranasal neoplasia), or otherwise, if there are any breeds that seem overrepresented. Ideally, I would have wanted to compare prevalence of disease between my study population and a reference population, but I can't obtain a reference population. The study population is made up of 117 cases encountered over 10 years or so. What I do have access to is the population of dogs registered to a particular area (in 2016). I'm not sure that any statistical tests would be valid.

Comment: Hence I'm just trying to evaluate whether, e.g. the proportion of Staffies that make up my study population, is similar to the proportion of Staffies in the registered dog population.

Comment: I re-tagged your question since `[spss]` tag did not seem to be valid in here since your question is not related to spss.